# sqlx unknown authentication plugin: auth_gssapi_client mariaDB

Tags: rust, mariadb, rust-tokio, rust-sqlx

connecting to a mariaDB database using sqlx
am passing a username and password to the connection string but the error reported is:

```
Error: Protocol("unknown authentication plugin: auth_gssapi_client")
```

There is a user set up on the server to use gssapi, but this connection string passes a user and password so should not be using it.
It still occurs when that user is DROP -ed also.

I tried removing the user and password details, and making them incorrect.
they appear to be ignored.

I would happily use gssapi if that is possible (on windows with sqlx) but i don't think that is possible

Minimal recreation:

main.rs

```
use sqlx::mysql::MySqlPool;

#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() -> Result<(), sqlx::Error> {
    let pool = MySqlPool::connect("mariadb://user:password@localhost:3306/database").await?;

    let row: (i64, ) = sqlx::query_as("SELECT $1")
    .bind(150_i64)
    .fetch_one(&pool).await?;

    assert_eq!(row.0, 150);

    println!("{:?}", row.0);

    Ok(())
}
```

cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "sqltest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
sqlx = {version = "0.7.2", features=["mysql", "runtime-tokio"] }
tokio = { version = "1.20.0", features = ["rt", "macros"]}
```

Comment: maybwe you can try https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/14dmbk6/mariadb_sqlx_unknown_authentication_plugin/

Comment: If you connect with non-existing user, and then get authentication challenge from server, do not wonder - it is a security feature, server can't tell right away "this user does not exist", that would be revealing too much.  So server does lets client perform authentication, but makes it fail without telling concrete reasons. Authentication plugins   for non-existing user could be chosen randomly, from the set of used plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a user that uses either mysql_native_authentication (normal, password-based), or gssapi.

```
CREATE USER user1@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password
USING PASSWORD('secret') OR gssapi;
```

The effect of this is that mysql_native_password is tried first and only if it fails, gssapi authentication is used as fallback

Comment: I will try this but the error comes when the connection string is using a user and password and there are no gssapi users on the server. It did not occur on a mysql server only mariadb

Comment: that's a security-related thing . If you connect with non-existing username, server  can't tell you directly or indirectly "this user exists, but bad password" or "this user does not exist".  This is telling too much. So, the server knows that user does not exist, yet acts as-if user would exist, and tells client to connect with some (random) authentication plugin. No matter what non-existing user answers to authentication challenge, server makes sure authentication fails. but it does not reveal that user did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The sqlx doesn't implement the MariaDB GSSAPI plugin. Current authentication plugins are [here](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/main/sqlx-mysql/src/protocol/auth.rs).

Implementing the client side shouldn't be too hard if you adapt the [Connector/C version from MariaDB](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/b323b5462db3751ed29fc3db83c855154f5f5ab4/plugins/auth/auth_gssapi_client.c#L84).

Adding an implementation would be in [src/connection/auth.rs](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/b1387057e5e6c6b72eacd01f491cb45854616502/sqlx-mysql/src/connection/auth.rs#L35) and it would:

Like [C/C](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/b323b5462db3751ed29fc3db83c855154f5f5ab4/plugins/auth/auth_gssapi_client.c#L84) retrieve:

- Principle name
- Optional mech name

Then like [C/C](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/b323b5462db3751ed29fc3db83c855154f5f5ab4/plugins/auth/gssapi_client.c#L61) and using [crate libgssapi](https://docs.rs/libgssapi/latest/libgssapi/):

- create a [ClientCtx](https://docs.rs/libgssapi/latest/libgssapi/context/struct.ClientCtx.html) and [push this as a response](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/b323b5462db3751ed29fc3db83c855154f5f5ab4/plugins/auth/gssapi_client.c#L93).

Comment: MariaDB's implementation also happens to work on any Windows , also outside of domain, , i.e without Kerberos. this is because it can use SSPI/Negotiate , which is implemented here https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/b323b5462db3751ed29fc3db83c855154f5f5ab4/plugins/auth/sspi_client.c . While gssapi and SSPI are similar, I'm not sure libgssapi can do everything that SSPI can, particularly "Negotiate" (which falls back to NTLM outside of domain).

Comment: Ah, ok [SSPI](https://github.com/devolutions/sspi-rs) is a crate too that seems more applicable.

Comment: This would be a solution, but the connection string is not attempting a gssapi authentication so the error is surprising

Comment: Its the server side that communicates the plugin required for the user, and then the client needs to implement the protocol in this answer for the communication. This is why @VladislavVaintroub's solution is to support two plugins, the first of which the client supports.

Comment: @HowMayIBeHelped, right, but this is how MySQL pluggable connections work 
 - server tells client what to use. Elsewhere, e.g in SQLServer, you can have more control how you connect on the client side.